# Error installing matplotlib for python on windows 10

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I've been doing python coding in my Aer E 160 class. I had to install python on my computer to finish a project, and while it installed on my Desktop just fine, my laptop is having an issue. I was able to install python from python.org just fine, Idle works. I was also able to use the command prompt to install numpy. My real issue is I can't install matplotlib on my laptop, even though I had no issue with it on my desktop. I keep getting the error: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ye8uykcy\matplotlib. How do I fix this? I've tried solutions on google but none of them have worked. Please help!

Comment: You should use `pip` to install matplotlib. `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing. I its what produces the error

Comment: Can you try again now. The wheels were not correctly set until an hour ago or so.

Comment: What does the wheels were not set correctly until an hour or so mean? Weirdly enough it did work when I popped open my command console and tried again. I just got back to my dorm and was amazed it wasn't working last night but did this morning. (I just started learning python through my aerospace 160 class recently, so this is an issue I am interested in knowing why it resolved itself for future refrence)

Comment: No, it did not resolve itself. The person uploading the wheels did a mistake which he corrected at roughly UTC/GMT 13:00.

Comment: Ah I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the .whl file from [lfd](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib).
2. pip install matplotlib: `pip install your.matplotlib.whl`

Comment: The wheels should be available from `pip` directly. No need to download them externally.

Answer (score 0):

Usually its the path that is not set

1. in cmd type path=c:\python34 or wherever your directory is.
2. then type command python -m pip install -U pip
3. then type command python -m pip install matplotlib
4. Done